# Changing fine uploader s3 policy error messages

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader

Is there a way to change the invalid S3 policy error messages displayed to the user with FineUploader? I've found how to customise the others, but I can't find reference to this in the JS so I'm assuming the message is sent from S3. Is there a way of intercepting the message and replacing it with something more meaningful?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't anything in place to adjust this message, mostly due to the fact that this is not an issue a user can fix. If there is a specific adjustment you'd like to see in future versions, please open up a case in the GitHub project's issue tracker.